# What is a good practice for reusing javascript in two JSP pages?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I have two JSP pages that must use the same javascript. The script attaches a function on an anchor. This function will call a database operation through the controller and service layer when user click on the anchors.

Both JSP pages has these anchors. Hence, it will be good if I can reuse this script in both pages. I am planning to create a JSP page that only has this script and include this pages in both jsp pages. Is this a good practice in re-using a javascript ? Are there any other better ways to do this ?

This is a snippet of the script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

         $('a[name*="like"]').click(function() {

             var hrefName = $(this).attr("name");
             var href = $(this);
             $.ajax({  
                  type: "POST",  
                  url: "likeARecipe",  
                  data: 'recipeId=' + $(this).attr("title") + '&operation=' + $(this).attr("name"),  
                  success: function() {  

                      if(hrefName == 'unlike')
                      {
                          $(href).attr("name","like");
                          $(href).text("like");
                      }else {
                          $(href).attr("name","unlike");
                          $(href).text("unlike");
                      } 
                  }  
                });  
                return false; 
         });



      });
```

**UPDATE**

I decided to put the script into a common.js script. I place this script under scripts/common.js.

I used  tag to render the URL to this script.

```
<spring:url value="/resources/scripts/common.js" var="common_js" />
<script src="${common_js}" type="text/javascript"><jsp:text/></script>
```

I configure spring to read this script by specfying these resources in a context file:

```
<resources location="/, classpath:/META-INF/web-resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>
```

However, spring did not load the script in the JSP Pages. Any suggestion on a way to trouble shot the problem ?

**UPDATE**

I found a solution to this problem. I have to modify the script. I enclosed the script inside a function():

```
(function(){
    alert("test");
    $(document).ready(function(){

         $('a[name*="like"]').click(function() {


             var hrefName = $(this).attr("name");
             var href = $(this);
             $.ajax({  
                  type: "POST",  
                  url: "likeARecipe",  
                  data: 'recipeId=' + $(this).attr("title") + '&operation=' + $(this).attr("name"),  
                  success: function() {  

                      if(hrefName == 'unlike')
                      {
                          $(href).attr("name","like");
                          $(href).text("like");
                      }else {
                          $(href).attr("name","unlike");
                          $(href).text("unlike");
                      } 
                  }  
                });  
                return false; 
         });
      });
```

})(jQuery);

Comment: Put them in a common `.js` file?

Comment: That's a good solution, you can also include the function in `.jspf` file. Not that it's a better solution - just ANOTHER solution ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an external .js file and reference it from both JSP pages, like this:

```
<script src="displaydate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Take a look here: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/external.shtml